# Textarea and modal not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm making out a ticket system for a repair shop with an option to update the status of the repair with canned responses. you can click a button, it opens a modal with canned response options, you click insert, and it inserts the response into the textarea below the button. everything works as it should on desktop, however, on mobile, the button for canned responses is not clickable, and the textarea can't be clicked either.

Button and textarea:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Status Update Message:  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" required rows="8" maxlength="750" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Canned Responses</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Diagnosing</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Dingmess">Hi,  Thanks for coming in.  We are currently diagnosing your machine...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Diagnosing"class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Diagnosis</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Dmess">Hi, We took a look at your device, and the issue is *.  It will be $...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Diagnosis" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Repair Approved</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Appmess">Thanks for your approval.  We will proceed with the fix and let you know when it's ready to pick...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Approved" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Repair Declined</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Decmess">Your repair has been marked as declined.  Please let us know...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Declined" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Parts Ordered</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Partmess">Parts have been ordered. We will notify you when we begin...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Parts" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>In Progress</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Progmess">Your repair is in progress. We will notify you when complete</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Progress" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Completed</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Compmess">Your repairs are complete, and your device is ready!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Completed" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Closed/Invoiced</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <p id="Closedmess">The ticket has been closed. Thank you.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" id="Closed" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript for insertion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Diagnosing").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Hi,  Thanks for coming in!  We are currently diagnosing your machine.  We\'ll let you know what the issue is as soon as we finish.');
  });
  $("#Diagnosis").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Hi, We took a look at your device, and the issue is *.  It will be $ +tax to repair.  Shall we proceed with the fix?');
  });
  $("#Approved").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Your device has been marked as approved!  We will proceed with the fix and let you know when it\'s ready to be picked up!');
  });
  $("#Declined").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Your repair has been marked as declined.  Please let us know if there is anything we can do to change your mind!');
  });
  $("#Parts").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Your parts have been ordered. We will let you know when we receive the parts and begin installing them.');
  });
  $("#Progress").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('We are currently working on your repair. We will notify you when it is done!');
  });
  $("#Completed").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('Hey there - your repair is all set!  We just finished cleaning it up so you can come pick it up and pay at your earliest convenience.  We *** and tested ***.');
  });
  $("#Closed").click(function(){
      $('#message').html('The ticket has been closed. Thank you.');
  });
});
```

Any thoughts as to why it wont work on mobile? i've looked for an hour or so, and i haven't found anyone with the same issue.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the script on Mobile. https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/qyrc0zx3/1/

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I'd make sure my scripts are in the following order and version:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#Diagnosing").click(function(){
          $('#message').html('Hi,  Thanks for coming in!  We are currently diagnosing your machine.  We\'ll let you know what the issue is as soon as we finish.');
      });
    ........
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: how did you test the button on mobile? jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I have an ftp server. The functionality works as expected on iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: android? if you dont have an android device, i could test it with the url

Comment: well i mean, you used my code, so it shouldnt change between servers